# D3.JS Change geometry from rect to path

Tags: d3.js, svg

Hi Stackoverflow folks,

I have a question on D3.js
Basically what I want to achieve is the change of the shape as below.
[image]

However, 
Once I finished the coding of the first drawing, the coordinate information was as below.

```
d3.selectAll('body').select('svg').append('rect')
.attr('x', 50)
.attr('y', 50)
.attr('width',150)
.attr('height',150)
.attr('fill','none')
.attr('stroke-width',2)
.attr('stroke','black')
```

I tried to change the shape as I clicked the rectangle.
So I made a click event. But!

the Parallelogram I want to achieve should be made of 'path'.
How do I change the square shape as I click the square.
Since I want to do 'animate'for the change, 
simply toggle off the square and and toggle on Parallelogram is not what I'm trying to make.

Can any please help me?
Or anyone has better solution for this??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the code corresponding to your animation attempt? A stack snippet would be perfect for this. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sounds like you need to apply a skew transform.

Comment: Have you considered/tried using Path instead of using Rect so that you don't have to switch later?